# Linq to EF - concatenate column name

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I kept the cases to 3 for brevity. I actually want to have 8. Is there a way to do something like this? Can I concatenate a column name that I want to access (e.g., ph.Img + ph.ImgCount.toString()) where I want the result: "ph.Img1"?

```
using (evEntities ent = new evEntities())

PostHousing ph = (from p in ent.PostHousings
                                  where p.HousingPostID == "24"
                                  select p).FirstOrDefault();

ph.Img + ph.ImgCount.toString() = completeFilePath
ent.SaveChanges();
```

This would save me from writing out a long switch/case with 8 case statements.

```
PostHousing ph = (from p in ent.PostHousings
                                  where p.HousingPostID == stringPostID
                                  select p).FirstOrDefault();

                switch (ph.ImgCount)
                {
                    case null:
                        ph.Img1 = completeFilePath;
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        ph.Img2 = completeFilePath;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        ph.Img3 = completeFilePath;
                        break;

                }
```

Comment: linq has no idea if .ImgXXX a column, it's just an object property. You can use Reflection, but it'll not worth the cost IMO.

Comment: So, a PostHousing has up to 8 images....that's a 1 to many relationship then? But held as individual properties rather than as a collection...

Answer (score 1):

You can use reflection to do this:

```
typeof(PostHousing).GetProperty("Img" + ((ph.ImgCount ?? 0) + 1))
    .SetValue(ph, completeFilePath);
```

Note that I'm changing null to 0 and adding 1 as that's what your switch statement is doing.